# How to partition an ActiveRecord relation into sequential groups for correcting data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We have some faulty data and I am trying to write a data_migration to fix some data. There are like 1mil faulty records.

what's the best way to partition these records into groups so I don't lock the database the entire time?

Say I have this query:
(faulty data)

```
apples = Apple.where(seed: "rotten")
```

Say I want to update these `apples` in batches of 5000. How do I do this?

Right now I have something like this...but it's weird. How do I do the first 5000, then the next 5000, until there are no more records? Let's say for complexity sake there are 1,104,000 records and now 1,105,000 records for a nice non-round number.

Here is my current solution:

```
class ChangeApples < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    disable_ddl_transaction!

    batch_separator = 20

    apples = Apple.where(core:"rotten")

    (0...batch_separator).each do |modulo|
      batch = apples.where("id % #{batch_separator} = #{modulo}")
      Rails.logger.info("Updating #{batch.count} apples with ids: #{batch.pluck(:id)}.")

      batch.update_all(eventable_type: "Edible")
    end
  end

  def self.down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be:

```
batch_separator = 5000
batches         = 0
while Apple.where(core:"rotten").
            limit(batch_separator).
            update_all(eventable_type: "Edible") > 0 do
  puts "Updating batch #{batches += 1}"
end
```

Untested code.

You might also put a sleep in the loop, and a commit (if not automatically issued). It's not ideal in terms of overall efficiency, but if you don't want to flood a busy OLTP database with requests then it's not too bad a method.